# Android Video View inside a framgent?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hello I have an issue playing a video from a url. I am using fragments and whenever I run my code I get this error:

> Error:(32, 34) error: no suitable constructor found for MediaController(MainFragment)
>   constructor MediaController.MediaController(Context) is not applicable
>   (actual argument MainFragment cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion)
>   constructor MediaController.MediaController(Context,boolean) is not applicable
>   (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>   constructor MediaController.MediaController(Context,AttributeSet) is not applicable
>   (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Here is my code:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String Video_url = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/102136471/20151113_223245.mp4";
public MainFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
   VideoView view = (VideoView) getView().findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    Uri video = Uri.parse(Video_url);

    view.setMediaController( new MediaController(this));
    view.setVideoURI(video);
    view.start();
    view.requestFocus();
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

}
```

I am not sure if this is the right way to open a video view inside a fragment or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do

```
view.setMediaController(new MediaController(getActivity()));
```

Access **context** in **Fragment** by using `getActivity()`

### corrected:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

// Inflate the layout for this fragment
VideoView view = (VideoView) v.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
Uri video = Uri.parse(Video_url);

view.setMediaController(new MediaController(getActivity()));
view.setVideoURI(video);
view.start();
view.requestFocus();

return v;

 }
```

Comment: I get the following error:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at animenetworks.animenetworks.MainFragment.onCreateView(MainFragment.java:29)

Comment: Ahh thank you MD but now it says "Cant play this video". Here is the variable decloration. private static final String Video_url = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/102136471/20151113_223245.mp4";

Comment: @EdgarAxe check your video. your issue is solved now.